# Issues converting websphere project to maven - Context Root Not Found

Tags: maven, websphere, libraries

There was an application  working properly for while but it wasn't a maven Project. Every library was managed by adding it manualy. So, inside of Spring Tool Suite, I right clicked in Configure >> Convert to Maven. Then I updated POM as below and there is no error in my IDE. Additionally, I can build the Project successfuly and I can see the class files in webinf/classes. However, I get "Context Root Not Found" in browser when  trying to access the application and I see the warnning when deploying it to server either in EAR or WAR "The application app could not be started as it could not be found at location app".

I am complete confuse about what can be the cause as all complains about libraries were fixed through POM. The only big diference I noted was that in Java Build Path, before I turned the Project to Maven, when I clicked in WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile there were a couple of libraries. Now, after turned the Project to Maven, when I click in it, there is no library. I reinstalled the server, created a new  profile and associated it to build path just in case it could be the problem but I am still seing no libraries when clicking in WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile. Do I have to add a dependency from IBM in POM? Is there any step to convert a old Project to Maven? I searched a lot and all recommendations I saw is related to add the dependency in POM which I have done as below but if there is na especific dependendy that I have to add in reason of being WebSphere I have no idea.

```xaml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app </artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
       <name>App Maven Webapp</name>
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
       <properties>
              <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
              <java-version>1.6</java-version>
              <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
              <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
              <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
       </properties>
       <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                     <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                     <version>4.1.1</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                     <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                     <version>2.5</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                  <version>1.9.12</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.version}</version>
              </dependency>
       </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Spring Tool Suite console:

```xaml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.488 seconds.

[WARNING ] CWWKZ0014W: The application app_original could not be started as it could not be found at location app.war.

[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://...:8080/app_original/

[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application app_original started in 2.565 seconds.

[WARNING ] Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://100.fwk4347180/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

URL [bundleresource://100.fwk4347180/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://100.fwk4347180/

[WARNING ] Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://99.fwk4347180/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

URL [bundleresource://99.fwk4347180/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://99.fwk4347180/

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\STS\ws\app_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\db2java.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\STS\ws\app_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jeapCore-03.02.1.2.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\STS\ws\app_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\upload.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.1.1\httpclient-4.1.1.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.1\httpcore-4.1.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.12\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.12\jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-asm\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
```

Comment: If you packaging just as war, then your context root might have changed. If it is not included in the ear and you just drop the war to dropins folder then your context root will be war file name without extension. You should be seeing it in the Liberty log when application is starting.

Comment: Gas, thank you for your comment but I am still facing problem to run the application. I placed some part of my console and I guess I did something wrong. Although there isn't complain about jars when deploing and I do see the classes outcome, I see some WARNINGS. Other point that might be related to my issue: is that normal that, before converting to maven, I clicked in WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile and there were a couple of libraries from IBM but now that it was turned to a maven Project, I can't see such libraries?

Comment: I see in the logs following: `[WARNING ] CWWKZ0014W: The application app_original could not be started as it could not be found at location app.war.`, so it looks like your `server.xml` is pointing to some old non existing app. 

`[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://...:8080/app_original/` shows that you have some application under `app_original`. And about libraries, you should have them now in the Maven Dependencies library folder.